# GCC error: expected ‘)’ before <function protoyprmeter> parameter

Tags: c, gcc

In a header file

`extern void Trace_Communication(communicationBlock_t mdbMessage);`

gives `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mdbMessage’`

I am sure that `communicationBlock_t` is in scope (and reliaze that it would be more efficient to pass a pointer)

If I copy the declaration of `communicationBlock_t` just before the `extern` offending line, the error is

```
error: conflicting types for ‘communicationBlock_t’  
note: previous declaration of ‘communicationBlock_t’ was here
```

Which seems to imply that the offending line has access to the declaration of `communicationBlock_t`

I guess that I am overlooking something trivial and obvious, but I have been coding all night and can no longer think straight ...

What am I doing wrong? Thanks 1 ,000,000

---

Update: my guess is that it's an include file tangle ...

```
typedef struct
{
  communicationMessage_t message;
  uint8_t                length;
#ifdef TESTING
   char                   commandName[32];    // for testing porpoises 
   DoRunTimeChecks        runTimeCheckCallback;
#endif      
} communicationBlock_t;
```

Comment: Make sure `Trace_Communication` and `mdbMessage` aren't `#define`d or `typedef`d anywhere.

Comment: +1 They aren't, but thanks for the hint

Comment: Is the "previous declaration of 'communicationBlock_t' was here" pointing to the right place and is it the declaration you expect?  What happens if you replace `communicationBlock_t` with `int` in the prototype for `Trace_Communication()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, folks. It was, as I suspected a deady embrace in #include files

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you're using a variable as a type name.  What does the declaration of `communicationBlock_t` look like?